# VBA - Open .xls files then copy 3 cells in one master .xls file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a noob with VBA and I've spent half a day to try to find the answer by my own before asking this question.

**Here is my situation:**
I have a database of 100 .xls file and I would like to copy 4 specifics cells of these files in one master files
. Product ID : in a merged case (IJK2)
. Dimension 1 : H71
. Dimension 2 : J71
. Dimension 3 : L71

Each file have the product ID as name (.xls)

Here is what my VBA code looks like:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\User\Documents\TEST\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "zmaster.xls" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
Range("H71:L71").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

It does'nt work... Could you help me to correct the code ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please be more specific about what exactly is not working? What is it doing? perhaps paste a screen shot of what you want, and what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try not closing the source workbook until after the paste. I think Excel clears the clipboard upon exit.